# How to change new theme for a content type

Tags: theming, hooks

Requirements: Create content type based theme.

I have a requirement to create content based theme, I mean if the content type is **article** then node view call theme-1 and if type is **basic page** then node view call theme-2

Answer (score 1):

[ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module can do this:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:

- individually-styled channels
- a front-page / "splash" screen
- a date/time-selected Christmas theme
- mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
- special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
- **content, user, or role -specific themes**
- indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
- testing your redesign safely on a live server
  ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [theme layer](https://www.drupal.org/node/933976) to add your logic and create separate [template files](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565) (**or** [theme hook suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)) to structure the markup for each of your content types. 
In case you only want to apply different style per node type instead of structure use [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) accordingly.

Comment: I am creating separate theme for each content type. Will you share some line of code?

Comment: Creating a theme, even a sub-theme for each content type will eventually overload your site and your work by any mean. Your answer is to broad to share code, the provided links contain a lot of code and working examples to start with. Note that the most of the code you are after is already in the theme's files, *.tpl.php and template.php files. If you provide a specific scenario I will happily share any code.

Comment: Thank you @mchar for your suggestion. There are lots of condition that I need to add with template.php and html.tpl.php so I decided to create separate theme for each content type.